# Is there a way with python to move files on windows by reading origin and destination directories from a conf file?

Tags: python, file, config, move

I'm trying to automate moving files from one windows directory to another, having the origin and destination directories in a config file.

I've gotten it to work if there is only 1 line in the config file containing the paths.
The shutil command also works if I hardcode the paths in the script, but that's not the idea.
I need to loop through a list of directories and run the code per origin and destination

This is the entry in the .conf file:

```
c:\\temp\O D |c:\\temp\D D
```

I split the line on the `|`, and and then I've tried the `os.path.join` and `os.path.normpath` but `shutil` keeps throwing the double backslashes if I add a row to the conf file.

If I add another row, then it throws this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\temp\D D \test1.txt'

this is my code so far....

```py
import shutil
import os
import os.path
import datetime

from pathlib import Path

filepath = r'c:\temp\acc.conf.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))

       a,b = line.split('| ')

       source= Path(a)
       source1=os.path.join(source)
       source_path = os.path.normpath(source1)
       #print(source_path)
       print(b)
       dst= Path(b)
       dst1=os.path.join(dst)
       dest_path = os.path.normpath(dst1)
       #print(dest_path)

       os.chdir(source_path)
       #print(os.getcwd())

       files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       run_time= now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
       for f in files:
           print(run_time + " - " + f + "- " + os.getcwd() + "- " + dest_path)
           #shutil.move(f, dest_path)
           print(f)
           print(dest_path)
           shutil.move(f, dest_path)
```

Comment: Small clarification: Do you allow your directories in the config to contain spaces? I.e., is your example conf line for moving files from `O D` with a space in it to `D D` with a space in it?

Comment: Next question: can you show the full conf file that generates the error message you quoted? Edit your question, and surround the file contents with triple backticks, like I did for your code, so we can see the exact input you're giving your program.

Comment: One more question: which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some changes, I was able to fix your code and get it working on my computer.

- Use `strip()` to remove the Windows style newline at the end of line and extra white space. This assumes that while your directory names might contain spaces, they won't end or start with a space.
- Instead of doing `chdir` to `source_path`, I open it in place. This allows me to use relative paths instead of exclusively absolute ones, and there's really no need to change the dir anyway. As a result, the files in `source_path` are referred to via `os.path.join(source_path, f)`.
- Put a try/except around `listdir` to handle the case where the directory does not exist.
- Test that `dest_dir` exists and is a directory, to avoid various problems.
- I tested this script and it works on my Windows 10 machine with Python 3.9.5 called from PowerShell. It works with one or multiple lines, and the paths can use `\\` or just `\`.

```py
import shutil
import os
import os.path
import datetime

from pathlib import Path

filepath = r'c:\temp\acc.conf.txt'
with open(filepath, "r") as fp:
   for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))

       a,b = line.split('|')

       source= Path(a.strip())
       source1=os.path.join(source)
       source_path = os.path.normpath(source1)
       print(b)
       dst= Path(b)
       dst1=os.path.join(dst)
       dest_path = os.path.normpath(dst1)

       if not os.path.isdir(dest_path):
           print(dest_path + " is not a directory, skipping.")
           continue

       try:
           files = os.listdir(source_path)
       except FileNotFoundError as e:
           print(e)
           continue

       now = datetime.datetime.now()
       run_time= now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
       for f in files:
           print(run_time + " - " + f + "- " + os.getcwd() + "- " + dest_path)
           print(f)
           print(dest_path)
           shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path, f), dest_path)
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Please consider accepting the answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: Just left of my answer, near the top, you should see a grey checkmark. Click it to signify this answer solved your problem. Cheers!